# Fixes for Bootstrap 4 Cropping

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a sliding overlay animation that works just fine without Bootstrap being imported, but when I import Bootstrap 4 (using it for a webpage I'm developing) the slides for the animation are cropped from the right and don't quite meet.

https://codepen.io/AdenMuhammad097/pen/YQPwJo

```css
#body1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#categories {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.clr:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#categories li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 27.85714285714286%;
  /* = (100-2.5) / 3.5 */
  padding-bottom: 32.16760145166612%;
  /* =  width /0.866 */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

#categories li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 1%;
}

#categories li:nth-child(6n+4) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

#categories li:nth-child(6n+4),
#categories li:nth-child(6n+5),
#categories li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  margin-top: -6.9285714285%;
  margin-bottom: -6.9285714285%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

#categories li:nth-child(6n+4):last-child,
#categories li:nth-child(6n+5):last-child,
#categories li:nth-child(6n+6):last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

#categories li * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
}

#categories li>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* HEX CONTENT */

#categories li img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#categories div h1,
#categories div p {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background-color: #008080;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}

#categories li h1 {
  bottom: 110%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#categories li h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#categories li p {
  padding-top: 50%;
  top: 110%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

#categories li div:hover h1 {
  bottom: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#categories li div:hover p {
  top: 50%;
  padding-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id='body1'>
  <ul id="categories" class="clr">
    <li class="pusher"></li>
    <li>
      <!--This is the Bright Hex-->
      <div>
        <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3156/2871027448_789b8d0552_b.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>Bright C.S. Building</h1>
        <p>Working problem sets, building out a new project, or (most likely) screwing around online...</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Bro change the width from 90% to 100% here #categories div h1, #categories div p{...

Comment: Thanks @BasantaMatia! Any idea on how to get them to touch in the middle?

Comment: I could not understand what do you mean by, how to get them to touch in the middle. Please explain bit more

Comment: When you hover over the hexagon, I want the two pieces that appear to touch in the middle. The end result should be that there appears to be only one blue overlay when the mouse hovers over the hexagon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expecting as in my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ashish9342/full/YvqLzw).

**URL** : https://codepen.io/Ashish9342/full/YvqLzw

I have changed the width to 100% and h1 margin to 0.

**Default values:** `h1-h6` has default margin. You need to remove this.

```css
//Added margin and width 100% 

#categories div h1, #categories div p{
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0 5%;
  background-color:#008080; background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only add this style

```
*, ::after, ::before {

        box-sizing: unset !important;
}
```

```css
#body1 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  background: white;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#categories {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
*, ::after, ::before {

        box-sizing: unset !important;
}
.clr:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

#categories li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 27.85714285714286%;
  /* = (100-2.5) / 3.5 */
  padding-bottom: 32.16760145166612%;
  /* =  width /0.866 */
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

#categories li:nth-child(3n+2) {
  margin: 0 1%;
}

#categories li:nth-child(6n+4) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

#categories li:nth-child(6n+4),
#categories li:nth-child(6n+5),
#categories li:nth-child(6n+6) {
  margin-top: -6.9285714285%;
  margin-bottom: -6.9285714285%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
  transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
}

#categories li:nth-child(6n+4):last-child,
#categories li:nth-child(6n+5):last-child,
#categories li:nth-child(6n+6):last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}

#categories li * {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
}

#categories li>div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -ms-transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* HEX CONTENT */

#categories li img {
  left: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#categories div h1,
#categories div p {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background-color: #008080;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.8);
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
  transition: top .2s ease-out, bottom .2s ease-out, .2s padding .2s ease-out;
}

#categories li h1 {
  bottom: 110%;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#categories li h1:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

#categories li p {
  padding-top: 50%;
  top: 110%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}


/* HOVER EFFECT  */

#categories li div:hover h1 {
  bottom: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#categories li div:hover p {
  top: 50%;
  padding-top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id='body1'>
  <ul id="categories" class="clr">
    <li class="pusher"></li>
    <li>
      <!--This is the Bright Hex-->
      <div>
        <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3156/2871027448_789b8d0552_b.jpg" alt="" />
        <h1>Bright C.S. Building</h1>
        <p>Working problem sets, building out a new project, or (most likely) screwing around online...</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```